# React Redux vs use-global-hook? Which is better?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

Working on my personal project and want to use hooks inside.
I've seen a global state implementation using hooks and my question is:
which one is better to use? Redux vs  [use-global-hook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-global-hook) ?
It seems super easy to manage with the global hook, but what about performance? What are advantages, disadvantages over redux?

Comment: Do you want to compare Redux with the concrete use-global-hook package or with `useReducer` + React.Context in general?

Comment: with that concrete package

Answer (score 1):

I've built apps using both methods and didn't notice any difference in performance; although Redux bindings are supposed to prevent unnecessary renders, I'm not sure how much of an impact this would make on the final performance of the app. Furthermore, Redux offers a time travelling debugger as well as a middleware API. The following article discusses this topic in more depth:

https://frontarm.com/james-k-nelson/when-context-replaces-redux/

Answer (score 1):

If you're planning to build a sizeable project of any complexity, Redux is going to provide a feature-rich store and state management via a unidirectional flow, actions, reducers, middleware, asynchronous thunks, etc. Redux is a mature pattern (based on Flux) with a great deal of "road-testing" and a thriving community. Also with Redux you'll be able to use fully stateful React class components and leverage the component lifecycle.

Global state hooks seem like a great upcoming solution for simpler components and problems where you want to keep your components functional and pure. I don't see any signs the performance would be any different, the only way to tell would be via empirical profiling.